# Cannot display any webpages even though internet connection is fine

Tags: internet-explorer-8, windows-server-2003

I have a terminal server that is not allowing anyone to connect to the internet via either a Leased Line or an ADSL connection. Both internet connections are up and running, and network services are running on the server as I can connect to shares on other servers.

The server has an IP address that has been correctly assigned via DHCP, and the default gateway is correct. Any suggestions on fixes (preferably without a restart so that I don't have to ask everyone to log off)? Thanks.

Comment: This should be on ServerFault as it's not a programming question.

Comment: Good point - how do I migrate?

Comment: One of the admins should migrate if for you.  I flagged it for them to look at and migrate to ServerFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there is two machines using same IP.

Comment: Not in this case - the IP is static (and not in the DHCP range), but has been for many years and we have had no new devices added recently.

Comment: This issue was because I had assigned 2x IP to one machine, and one of them (used for a Secure Tunnel) had errounisly been assigned via DHCP. Changing that IP solved the problem.